# Troubles when evaluating some limits with trig functions

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I know that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\sin x}{x}} = 1$, but I **cannot** use L'Hopital Rule as we haven't studied it yet. Here are the limits:

- $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1}{\frac{\sin(1 - \sqrt{x})}{x - 1}} = \lim_{t \to 0}{\frac{\sin(1 - \sqrt{t + 1})}{t}} = \lim_{t \to 0}{\frac{\sin(1 - \sqrt{t + 1})}{t}} \cdot \frac{1 - \sqrt{t + 1}}{1 - \sqrt{t + 1}} = \lim_{t \to 0}{1 \cdot \frac{1 - \sqrt{t + 1}}{t}} =\space ?$
  The substitution is for $t = x - 1$. I really don't know how to go on, since the result should be $-\dfrac{1}{2}$. I tried to multiply and divide by $1 + \sqrt{t + 1}$ which is the usual continuation but if I didn't make a mistake I cannot solve it like that.
- $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^3}}$
  Here I continued by rewriting $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and doing the calculations. Then I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one,  put $1-\sqrt x=u\implies x=(1-u)^2$

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sin(1-\sqrt x)}{x-1}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u}{(1-u)^2-1}$$

$$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u}u\cdot\frac1{\lim_{u\to0}(u-2)}$$

---

For two,  $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}=\frac1{\lim_{x\to0}\cos x}\cdot \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\cdot \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$$

Putting $x=2u$ in $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{1-\cos2u}{4u^2}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{2\sin^2u}{4u^2}=\frac12\left(\frac{\sin u}u\right)^2$$

Comment: Thank you. Now everything is clear.

Answer (score 2):

For example

$$\frac{\sin(1-\sqrt x)}{x-1}=-\frac1{1+\sqrt x}\frac{\sin(1-\sqrt x)}{1-\sqrt x}\xrightarrow [x\to 1]{}-\frac12\cdot 1=-\frac12$$

Comment: Oh this is a nice one! I didn't notice that at all.